# d language concurrency with recursion

Tags: recursion, concurrency, d, phobos

I have been trying to implement a factorial function using the actor model with the d language.
My objective is to use to create actor to calculate each part alone e spawn a new actor to make the next.
I am just a beginner with D, so I'm just learning how to use the language. My objective is to expand the factorial implementation to much more. This is just a test.

Here is my problem:
I'm trying to implement the factorial using recursion; the fact function will create a new fact thread for next number in line, unless it has reached the base condition.

My code:

```
void fact(Tid tid)
{

        int fact = 1;
        receive
        (
        (int i)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                writeln("End of recursion");
            }
            else
            {
                fact *= i;
                send(thisTid, i-1);
            }
        }
    );
    send(tid, fact);
}

void main()
{

        auto tid = spawn(&fact, thisTid);
        int x = 3;
        send(tid, x);
        auto fact = receiveOnly!(int);
        writeln(fact);
}
```

I don't even know if that's possible, in any case it does not work. If I try to add a spwn in fact function it returns the following error:

```
src/main.d(62): Error: template std.concurrency.spawn does not match any function template declaration
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/dmd/phobos/std/concurrency.d(399): Error: template std.concurrency.spawn(T...) cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(int*,Tid)
src/main.d(63): Error: template std.concurrency.send does not match any function template declaration
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/dmd/phobos/std/concurrency.d(463): Error: template std.concurrency.send(T...) cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(_error_,int)
```

So, is it possible to do what I am trying to do? How?
If not, is there any plans to make some thing like that possible?

Please, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be way off base here, but from that error message it looks to me like dmd is not using the `fact` that you think it is using, in your call to `spawn`. You have several integers named `fact`, and although in this (obviously cut down, since it's not 400 lines) example none of them would conflict, in the full code my guess is one of them does (because `&fact` would be an `int*` if `fact` was an `int`).

Try renaming the function to factorial or some such, and changing the `spawn` call where appropriate. Make sure not to change the integers.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me. What DMD version are you using? Perhaps try upgrading to 2.059 if you aren't already on it.

(Note: I say it *works* in that it compiles and runs. It doesn't give the write answer because `fact` will only `receive` one number before it returns, so it just returns three. You'll need to have the `receive` in a loop)

```
admin@poita ~% cat test.d
import std.stdio;
import std.concurrency;

void fact(Tid tid)
{
    int fact = 1;
    receive
    (
        (int i)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                writeln("End of recursion");
            }
            else
            {
                fact *= i;
                send(thisTid, i-1);
            }
        }
    );
    send(tid, fact);
}

void main()
{
    auto tid = spawn(&fact, thisTid);
    int x = 3;
    send(tid, x);
    auto fact = receiveOnly!(int);
    writeln(fact);
}

admin@poita ~% dmd test.d
admin@poita ~% ./test
3
admin@poita ~%
```

Comment: My question was about if it is some how possible to make it work. I have plan fr the future that depends on this functioning as expected.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make it work. There's nothing wrong with a thread sending a message to itself, or spawning a new thread using the same function. The only problem with the code you have is that your algorithm doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot find the problem here and, when I try to create a new thread, it rises a template exception. I use the same call method for both calling outside and inside the function, it works outside, but does not work inside.